# Find a match between 2 columns with only first parts of a multi digit integer

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm doing a search funtion from python3 that looks into a sqllite3 database.
I have a table called 'numberseries' with various columns.
Some of the columns are "customername" "number_from", number_to, "total".

The number_from and number_to fields contains the starting point and end point of a series of numbers.

For instance:
"Customer XYX" has numbers in the range from 80201110 to 80201129.
Those 2 numbers are entered into "numbers_from" and "numbers_to" respectively.
The "total" column will contain the numerical difference between the entries. In this case 20.

I've made a simple query that returns the row based on:

```
"Select * from numberseries where :value BETWEEN numbers_from and numbers_to;"
```

This works fine with a full 8 digit number.

However:

The users want a function that returns the same data, but also if they only enter the first 5 digits of the number.

For instance if they enter 80201, it should return all rows that includes 80201 as the first 5 digits in the range between "number_from" and "number_to".

it's not enough to just look at the "number_from" column only with a like statement, as the "total" might be 1000+ numbers

I hope this makes sense.
I'm by no means an sql expert and I'm having a hard time with this problem.

UPDATE:
I got a request for clarification.

Sample data is a table with a number for rows. for simplicity it only has the following columns:

- id
- customer name
- numbers_from
- numbers_to
- total

a sample customer could be:

```
1, "the best customer", 80201110, 80201149, 40
```

input could be: 8020113 (last digit missing) and i would still need to match the example row as 8020113x is in the range between 80201110 and 80201149.

Comment: Cast the integer values as character.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I added additional clarification in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment to the other answer you got, what you actually want is this:

```
select * from numberseries 
where :value in (
  substr(numbers_from, 1, length(:value)), 
  substr(numbers_to, 1, length(:value))
)
```

or:

```
select * from numberseries 
where :value BETWEEN substr(numbers_from, 1, length(:value)) and numbers_to || ''
```

Comment: it still didnt catch values where the input value was between the two, but not an exact match. 

eg. XXXX5 in the range of XXXX4XXX and XXXX6XXX

The modification below seems better:

select * from numberseries 
where :value BETWEEN
  substr(numbers_from, 1, length(:value)) and
  substr(numbers_to, 1, length(:value))

Comment: @BLC Check my 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the numbers in the data are always 8 characters, then you can treat it like a string, add a bunch of zeros and convert back to a number:

```
where cast(substr(value || '00000000', 1, 8) as int) BETWEEN numbers_from and numbers_to;
```

Comment: This works better, but it still misses out on some rows. For instance it doesnt return a record that has number_from = 80101500 and number_to = 80101599 and input value is the 5 first digits.

Comment: I elaborated on yours so it works:
Select * from numberseries
where number_from BETWEEN cast(substr('8010' || '00000000', 1, 8) as int) and cast(substr('8010' || '99999999', 1, 8) as int)
OR number_to BETWEEN cast(substr('8010' || '00000000', 1, 8) as int) and cast(substr('8010' || '99999999', 1, 8) as int);